# Add button to UIPickerView to go to next number

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, int, uipickerview

I have 3 columns on my `pickerView` and its representing a 3-digit number. Is there any function I can add to a `UIButton` that makes the wheel go round? For example, when it's showing "119", with a press of the `UIButton`, it should go to "120". Here's what I have so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

let numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return numbers[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let val1 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    let val2 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    let val3 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]

    label.text = "\(val1) \(val2) \(val3)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code, simplified. `buttonPressed` will cause `pickerView` to go to the next number. When it reaches 999, it turns back to 000.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        changeLabelText()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(row)"
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        changeLabelText()
    }

    fileprivate func num(_ i: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: i)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        let currentNum = num(0) * 100 + num(1) * 10 + num(2)
        let nextNum = currentNum + 1

        pickerView.selectRow(nextNum % 1000 / 100, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        pickerView.selectRow(nextNum % 100 / 10, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
        pickerView.selectRow(nextNum % 10, inComponent: 2, animated: true)

        changeLabelText()
    }

    fileprivate func changeLabelText() {
        label.text = "\(num(0)) \(num(1)) \(num(2))"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use the `selectRow` method, which will select a row of the specific column (aka component). The method also has the option to animate this change. Add a button to the storyboard and connect it to a method such as the following:

```
@IBAction func go120(_ sender: Any) {
  pickerView.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
  pickerView.selectRow(2, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
  pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 2, animated: true)  
}
```